# How can return string from database using dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I tried but it gives this error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@imageid"

controller.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("download/{id:int}")]
    public String Getfiles(int imageid)
    {

        return _ShopDataProvider.DownloadImage(imageid);

    }
```

class.cs

```
public String  DownloadImage(int imageid)
    {
        using(IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
        {

            string sQuery0 = "SELECT path FROM Shop WHERE ShopId = @imageid";
            dbConnection.Open();
            String Path = dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefault<String>(sQuery0, new { ShopId = imageid });

            return Path;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a parameter in your SQL query named `@imageid` but not providing a value for it. You're providing a value for the parameter `@ShopID` (`new { ShopId = imageid }`), which your SQL query doesn't use.

Change `new { ShopId = imageid }` to `new { imageid = imageid }`

Please refer to the [documentation](https://dapper-tutorial.net/queryfirstordefault).

Comment: there are values in my DB error is fixed but return string is null when i changed SELECT path FROM Shop WHERE ShopId = @imageid to Select ShopName ..etc

Comment: `String Path = dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefault<String>(sQuery0, new { imageid = 1 });` it return me a values but `String Path = dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefault<String>(sQuery0, new { imageid = imageid });` it doesnt return value

Comment: @DulangaHeshan Use a debugger. Look at the value of `imageid`. Does it have the value you're expecting?

Comment: yes thnks i fixed error was  `[Route("download/{id:int}")] ` here thank you very much brother